# More efficient way to formulate if/elif statement based on outcome of np.random.random?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, random

I am attempting to speed up my code which has a long if/elif statement of the following form:

```
random = np.random.random()
tot = a + b + c + d

if random < a/tot:
   var1 += 1
elif a/tot < random < (a+b)/tot:
   var1 -= 1
elif (a+b)/tot < random < (a+b+c)/tot:
   var2 += 1
elif (a+b+c)/tot < random < 1:
   var2 -= 1
```

I have tried to figure out a way to do this with a dictionary but I can't figure out how I would index into it. The code works as is, however I am trying to speed up this section of the code which takes a large chunk of the runtime. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Well an obvious optimisation: `elif a/tot < random < ...`, `elif (a+b)/tot < random < ...`, `elif (a+b+c)/tot < random < ...`, you've _already_ verified these in the previous `if`/`elif` bodies, you only need the second comparison of each `elif`

Comment: Shouldn't the very last comparison be `< 1` (or just leave it out)? Using `< tot` could be false. Also what if `(a+b)/tot == random`? In your example this case is not covered.

Comment: Is `var2` really coupled to `var1`? Written that way, each event (a,b,c,d) is completely independent of one another (there's no intersection between them)

Comment: Yes @a_guest, this was my mistake.

Comment: Rather than dividing by tot, why don't you multiple random by tot once prior to the if

Comment: You are also getting false results if random is exactly equal to any of the level values. One side should be `<=`

Comment: I've added an answer which I believe has minimum steps and minimum expensive operations (like division).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [bisection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) to determine in what "bin" your random number falls:

```py
bins = np.cumsum([0., a, b, c, d])
bins /= bins.sum()

updates_var1 = [1, -1, 0, 0]
updates_var2 = [0, 0, 1, -1]

index = bisect.bisect(bins, random) - 1
var1 += updates_var1[index]
var2 += updates_var2[index]
```

This solution can be vectorized by using [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) instead of [`bisect.bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect).

Comment: Perhaps replace the in-place division with `bins = bins / bins.sum()`, so that it can handle integers too?

Comment: @MariosMitalidis I added `0.` as the first element, so the array would implicitly be created as `float` type.

Answer (score 0):

The only few things I see here are:

1. you only need the second condition (the first was already checked in the previous if, so you know that the inverse of it is true)
2. if the `if-else` chain is inside a loop, and `a,b,c,d` are fixed inside this loop, then compute the sums and divisions in advance (before entering the loop)
3. change the last `elif` by `else`

Resulting in

```
# if a,b,c,d,tot are FIXED inside some external loop
# you should calculate tot,P1,P2,P3 OUTSIDE the loop
tot = a + b + c + d
P1=a/tot
P2=(a+b)/tot
P3=(a+b+c)/tot

# considering a,b,c,d,tot are fixed inside the loop
# the loop should start here
random = np.random.random()
if random < P1:
   var1 += 1
elif random < P2:
   var1 -= 1
elif random < P3:
   var2 += 1
else:
   var2 -= 1
```

Another thing you can try is putting that if-else chain into a function and using numba, pythran or cython to generate a compiled code for it.

Comment: If `P1`-`P3` are only being used once, why precompute them?

Comment: I assume the if-else chain is inside a loop and P1, P2, and P3 don't change inside the loop...  If these probabilities change inside the loop, then there's no point in computing them beforehand

Comment: `rand_tot = random * tot` then use rand_tot rather than dividing by tot in several sports

Answer (score 0):

assuming each item is equally likely, it might be worth doing:

```
a_b = a+b
a_b_c = a_b+c
random = np.random.random() * (a_b_c+d)

if a_b < random:
   var1 += 1 if a < random else -1
else:
   var2 += 1 if a_b_c < random else -1
```

this will cause each iteration to perform two `if` statements, whereas your version only required one for `a` but four for `d`

then again if significant amount of time is spent here, then you might be worth doing something else.  e.g. vectorise things, or rely on some analytical stats results so you don't have to draw as many samples

Answer (score 0):

This may be the most efficient by removing the divisions:

```
tot = a + b + c + d
random = np.random.random() * tot

if random < a:
   var1 += 1
elif random < a+b:
   var1 -= 1
elif random < a+b+c:
   var2 += 1
else:
   var2 -= 1
```